# How to set velocity layout directory and default template with spring in boot application.properties

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-boot, velocity

If we don't use spring boot ,we could user velocity.properties just like this
`tools.view.servlet.layout.directory =layout/ 
tools.view.servlet.layout.default.template=default.vm`

or use this bean in our springmvc project

```
<bean id="velocityViewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.velocity.VelocityLayoutViewResolver">
    <property name="cache" value="false" />
    <property name="layoutUrl" value="/layout/default.vm" />
    <property name="prefix" value="/templates/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".vm" />
    <property name="exposeSpringMacroHelpers" value="true" />
    <property name="contentType" value="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />
    <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.velocity.VelocityLayoutView" />
    <!--  <property name="toolboxConfigLocation" value="classpath:web/config/toolbox.xml" /> 
  <property name="exposeSessionAttributes" value="true" /> -->
</bean>
```

but I want to know how to set velocity layout through application.properties.
And I also has some confusion about the "spring.velocity.properties.* =" in application.properties. How and when we could use it.I could't find one demo about this.

Comment: See: http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.3.3.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-customize-view-resolvers-velocity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I solved my problem.And forgive me I did not describe the problem clearly.We use VelocityLayoutViewResolver  as viewClass in  our project ,while velocityViewResolver  is  default  viewClass in spring boot.On the other hand，spring boot  support velocity-tools 2.0.While spring 4.0 did not.And I did not how to config  velocity-tools 2.0 with VelocityLayoutViewResolver  in spring boot at first.And at last I solve my problem  through this way:

```
  <bean id="velocityViewResolver"       class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.velocity.VelocityLayoutViewResolver">
            <property name="cache" value="false" />
            <property name="layoutUrl" value="/layout/default.vm" />
            <property name="prefix" value="/templates/" />
            <property name="suffix" value=".vm" />
            <property name="exposeSpringMacroHelpers" value="true" />
            <property name="contentType" value="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />
            <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.velocity.VelocityLayoutView" />
           <property name="attributesMap">
            <map>
                <entry key="csrfTool"><bean class="com.XXX.velocity.CSRFTool"/></entry>
                <entry key="shiro"><bean class="com.XXX.velocity.Permission"/></entry>
            </map>
        </property>
        </bean>
```

and start with

```
@Configuration
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(new String[] {
                "classpath*:web/config/viewResolver.xml",
            }, args);
}
}
```

And very thanks Stéphane Nicoll answer.

Answer (score 0):

There are a bunch of resources at your disposal already. There is [a sample](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/master/spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-velocity) that you can try. And you can also review the [spring.velocity properties in the documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#common-application-properties).

You'll see looking at your XML sample above a lot of similarities, that is:

```
spring.velocity.cache=false
spring.velocity.prefix=/templates/
spring.velocity.suffix=.vm
spring.velocity.expose-spring-macro-helpers=true
spring.velocity.content-type=text/html;charset=UTF-8
spring.velocity.expose-session-attributes=true
```

I mean it's *literally* the same names as the ones in the XML

If you want to set the `viewClass` then you can create a `VelocityViewResolver` of your own named `velocityViewResolver` and we'll use that.

The `spring.velocity.properties` does what it states. It's additional properties that can be set to further customize the `VelocityEngineFactory`.

Check [`VelocityAutoConfiguration`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/v1.2.5.RELEASE/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/velocity/VelocityAutoConfiguration.java) for more details.

Comment: Thank your answer very much.In fact ,there is not option about  "spring.velocity.layoutUrl" in  application.properties.And the demo in github  is very easy,the code like #set($layout = "/layout/register_layout.vm") do not work in my project.

Comment: Right, I've added an issue for the layourUri, see https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/3732